# When can we interchange “who/which" and "that”?

Tags: relative-pronouns

So far I thought the words **who and that** are usually interchangeable:

> 1. There is the man who saw me.
> 2. There is the man that saw me.

Both sentences seem fine, *who* can be replaced with *that*. But in the following examples:

> 1. This is the man to whom I spoke.
> 2. This is the man to that I spoke.

The #2 sounds odd, which is why I don’t think it might be correct.

The same observation for the words **which and that**, while

> 1. This is the ball which we used today.
> 2. This is the ball that we used today.

Seem to be in order and *which* can be replaced with *that*. But in the following examples the #2 sounds odd again.

> 1. This is the ball with which I scored.
> 2. This is the ball with that I scored.

I wonder if there’s any rule regarding the interchangeability of the above mentioned words.

Comment: I hope you don't mind  - I edited your question because the *to* didn't work with the verb you were using ... I won't be offended it you roll it back. Or you can just fiddle about with a full stop and my name will disappear from your post!

Comment: @Araucaria, on the contrary: I feel honored and flattered, the post looks far more better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observations are pretty precise.

In Standard English (whatever that is), relative *that* is not used **a)** to head non-restrictive ('supplementary') relative clauses or **b)** as the object of an immediately preceding ('pied-piped') preposition. Only *wh-* forms (*who/whom*, *which*) are used in these contexts.

> **a)** That is John, {whom/<sup>∗</sup>that} I interviewed yesterday.
>   **b)** This is the ball with {which/<sup>∗</sup>that} I scored.

However, *that* may head a clause in which it acts as object of a 'stranded' preposition:

> <sup>ok</sup>This is the ball that I scored **with**.

In colloquial English rule **a)** is relaxed, because in improvised speech the distinction between restrictive and non-restrictive clauses is not so strongly marked as it is in composed speech—a restrictive clause often occurs to a speaker 'after the fact', so it is pragmatically non-restrictive even when it is semantically restrictive. But rule **b)** is almost universally observed in all registers.

---

<sup>∗</sup> *marks an expression as unacceptable*

Comment: Well done! Thank you! It’s a real pleasure to read whatever you write. +1

Answer (score 2):

When we have 'restrictive' or 'integrated' relative clauses we can usually use *that* instead of *which* or *who(m)*. We don't usually use *that* with non-restrictive relative clauses:

- *Your Dad, that I've known for many years, is a really nice guy. (wrong)

There are some special cases when we can't use *that* with restrictive relative clauses either. The following sentence is fine:

- That's the man that you were talking with.

However, if we move the preposition to the front of the relative clause, *that* cannot be the complement of the preposition. We have to use *whom* or *which* as appropriate:

- That's the man **with whom** you were talking.
- *That's the man **with that** you were talking. (wrong)

[Notice that we cannot use *who* as the complement of a preposition. We have to use *whom*:

- *That's the man **with who** you were talking. (wrong)

Many writers on this site tell people not to use *whom*, but this is one situation where you have to!]

Another situation in which it's better not to use *that*, is after the demonstrative pronoun, 'pointy' *that*.

- #Do not do that that you know to be wrong. (awkward)

This is not grammatically wrong, but it's a bit awkward, and it can be difficult to read. Lastly we may want to contrast the difference between a person or thing that might have done something. In this case we may want to say *who or which*. This cannot work with the word *that*:

- Never trust in any people or in any things who, or which, you cannot actually see.
- *Never trust in any people or in any things who, or that, you cannot actually see. (wrong)

The Original Poster is, therefore, correct: we cannot always use *that* instead of *who(m)* or *which*. The following sentences from the original question are ungrammatical, because *that* cannot appear as the object of a preposition:

- *This is the man **to that** I spoke. (wrong)
- *This is the ball **with that** I scored. (wrong)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sometimes on ELL we add little footnotes to our posts explaining symbols like \* and # because not everyone here is familiar with them.

Comment: @snailboat Do you think that's more helpful than doubling up (i.e. putting *(wrong)* or *(awkward)* next to the examples)? [Missing *(awkward)* has been duly added!] I'll basically take your guidance on that ....

Comment: Oh, your edit is fine.  I figure anything that gets the point across is good :-)